# Inputing a dictionary and a list of dictionaries and replacing only when a integer is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following:

```
d1={"00f_125":["A","2","3"],
    "00f_126":["1","2","3"],
    "00f_127":["T","2","3"],
    "00f_128":["T","2","3"]}

d2=[{"marker":"00f_125","1":"T"},
    {"marker":"00f_126", "1":"G"},
    {"marker":"00f_127","1":"T"}]
```

I would like to replace when there is only an integer present. This is the output I would like:

```
d3={"00f_125":["A","2","3"],
    "00f_126":["G","2","3"],
    "00f_127":["T","2","3"],
    "00f_128":["T","2","3"]}
```

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The syntax of `d1` seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
d1={"00f_125":["A","2","3"],"00f_126":["1","2","3"],"00f_127":["T","2","3"],"00f_128":["T","2","3"]}
d2=[{"marker":"00f_125","1":"T"},{"marker":"00f_126", "1":"G"},{"marker":"00f_127","1":"T"}]

for i in d2:
    if i["marker"] in d1:
        if d1[i["marker"]][0] in i:
            d1[i["marker"]][0] = i[d1[i["marker"]][0]]
```

**Output:**

```
{'00f_125': ['A', '2', '3'],
 '00f_126': ['G', '2', '3'],
 '00f_127': ['T', '2', '3'],
 '00f_128': ['T', '2', '3']}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to do in-place on `d1`:

```
for elem in d2:
    marker = elem["marker"] 
    if "1" in d1[marker]:          # is that specific int in d1?
        i = d1[marker].index("1")  # if so, then find its index
        d1[marker][i] = elem["1"]  # and replace it with your desired value
```

This is, of course, an oversimplification. If you have more than one key besides "marker", you might want to put all of those keys into a list within that dict (e.g.

```
d2=[{"marker": "00f_125", "modifications": ["1": "G", "2": ...]}, ...]
```

), which would make it easier to iterate through them without hardcoding the value like I did above.

If you wanted to produce a separate dict `d3` without modifying the original, then you could make a shallow or deep copy of `d1` before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
d3 = d1.copy()
for i in d2:
    key = i['marker']
    if key in d3.keys():
        if (d3[key][0].isdigit()):
            d3[key][0] = i['1']
print(d3)
```

You can copy d1 to d3 and directly make changes in d3. For every list in d2, if the marker value is present in d3, then check if the first element is an integer. If it is, then replace that number with the character value.

This is the output of the above code.

```
d3 = {'00f_126': ['G', '2', '3'], 
'00f_125': ['A', '2', '3'], 
'00f_127': ['T', '2', '3'], 
'00f_128': ['T', '2', '3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another generic approach without specifying the keys

```
for i in d2:
    for key in i.keys():
        if i.get(key) in d1:
            lis_val = d1.get(i.get(key))
        if key in lis_val:
            lis_val[lis_val.index(key)] = i.get(key)
```

**Output:**

```
{
  '00f_125': ['A','2','3'],
  '00f_126': ['G','2','3'],
  '00f_127': ['T','2','3'],
  '00f_128': ['T','2','3']
}
```